# How do I make channels in plaster for electric lines?

Tags: wiring, plaster

Most of my walls consist of solid plaster over masonry, which makes electrical work difficult to say the least. I want to add some wiring to an existing wall in order to add light fixtures to a room which currently lacks them. Since there are no stud bays to run wires, I will need to cut channels in the plaster to run armored cable or conduit.

What are the best tools and techniques for accomplishing this?

Comment: how thick is the plaster? Is there any thing supporting the plaster such as lath or mesh?

Comment: How deep do wiring codes require the channel to be, and how must the cable be armored/protected?

Comment: @mikes the plaster is at least 3/4 of an inch thick based on some exploratory drilling. It appears to be applies directly on top of the concrete block; I'm not sure if there's any mesh or lathe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Channelling chisel on SDS drill.

[image]

For short runs a brick bolster works reasonably well (and produces much less dust)

[image]

Deeply scoring the plaster with a knife beforehand to define the edges of the channel may help to prevent large irregular chunks being removed.